# Mysql how to do this?

Tags: mysql

I need to select records from table,but one field(id2 as example) replace with value from other table with id==id2 from first table

Comment: Can you explain that in more detail? I'm confused about what you are trying to do: Are you trying to SELECT data from two tables, or are you trying to UPDATE one table with data from another? What columns are in the tables, and what are you trying to replace?

Comment: i need to Select data from two tables,and get value of id(table2),where id==id2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to SELECT the rows from a table where a column value is present in another tables column, then you need to use JOIN:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.id = table2.id2
```

[Read this blog post by Jeff Atwood on the different joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html).